# Deleting multiple records in IndexedDB based on index

Tags: indexing, indexeddb, database-cursor

I am using IndexedDB and I have two object stores: *equip* (represents different equipment, primary key *tagNo*) and *equipParts* (represents the parts of a piece of equipment and has an index which is based on the tag number/serial number, primary key *seqNo*, with a field *tagNo* which represents the equipment that part is part of).

If I delete a record in *equip*, I want to delete all records in *equipParts* bearing the *tagNo* of *equip* (just like "where equipParts.tagNo = equip.tagNo").

Excerpt from my code:

```js
var tx = db.transaction(["equip", "equipParts"],"readwrite");
var estore = tx.objectStore("equip");
var pstore = tx.objectStore("equipParts");
var tagIndex = pstore.index("by_tagNo");
var pdestroy = tagIndex.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(tagno)); //opens all records bearing the selected tag number
pdestroy.onsuccess = function() {
    var cursor = pdestroy.result;
    if (cursor) {
        if (cursor.value.tagNo == tagno) {
            pstore.delete(cursor.value.seqNo); //I guess I'm wrong here
        }
        cursor.continue;
    }
}
pdestroy.onerror = function() {
    alert("Deletion attempt NG");
}
var ereq = estore.delete(tagno);
ereq.onsuccess = function(e) {
    alert("Form deletion OK");
    window.location = "index.html";
}
ereq.onerror = function(e) {
    alert("Form deletion NG");
    window.location = "index.html";
}
db.close();
```

The problem is that only the record in *equip* is deleted; the records in *equipParts* stay there. Is there a way to delete multiple records in an IndexedDB object store based on a non-unique index (which can be the primary key of the parent object store)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to get primary keys to delete the records.

```js
var pdestroy = tagIndex.openKeyCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(tagno)); 
pdestroy.onsuccess = function() {
  var cursor = pdestroy.result;
  if (cursor) {
      pstore.delete(cursor.primaryKey);
      cursor.continue();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, but not efficient

```js
var pdestroy = tagIndex.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(tagno)); 
pdestroy.onsuccess = function() {
  var cursor = pdestroy.result;
  if (cursor) {
      cursor.delete();
      cursor.continue();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is the second not efficient?

Comment: `openCursor` return `IDBCursorWithValue`, which requires reading record value, whereas the first one return `IDBCursor` without record value.

Comment: Thanks.  Is is true though only the later is doing the entire delete within the same transaction?

Comment: Deleting records while the cursor is open is buggy on Safari. The cursor would become null even when there're additional matching records. It's more reliable to grab all the primary keys, then call `IDBObjectStore.delete()` on each of them.

Comment: Be aware that you can't call `delete()` (or IDBCursor.update()) on cursors obtained from `IDBIndex.openKeyCursor()`. For such needs, you have to use `IDBIndex.openCursor()` instead.

Comment: i dont get it how the `cursor.continue()` statement works without a loop @KyawTun

Comment: it seems `cursor.continue()` will trigger request .onsuccess again

Comment: @datdinhquoc You are right, it will create a new request, but use [same source](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbcursor-continue), so it will call same `onsuccess` callback where `continue` was called.

Comment: mamma mia, IDBIndex should have `.delete`

Answer (score 2):

I deleted multiple records belonging to an index by this way using [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) :

```js
var tx = idb.transaction("MyObjectStore", 'readwrite');
var index = tx.store.index('my_relid_idx');
var pdestroy = index.openCursor(RelID);
pdestroy.then(async cursor => {
    while (cursor) {
        cursor.delete();
        cursor = await cursor.continue();
    }
})
```

Comment: this is using jakearchibald/idb, not vanilla IndexedDB apis

Answer (score 1):

I found out an easiest approach with this

```js
index.iterateCursor(IDBKeyRange, (cursor) => {
  if(cursor) {
    cursor.delete();
    cursor.continue();
  }
});
```

that way if you have it under an async function you can just use the

```js
await index.iterateCursor...
```

and wait for the promise on the other side

Comment: this works, but why shouldn't be a 'delete' method directly under IDBIndex just as .get and .getAll

Comment: update: i can't see the method iterateCursor documented in IDBIndex; i've tried again, it's not working @sebas

Comment: `.iterateCursor` seems an old feature?: https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb/search?q=iterateCursor